# ASP.NET MVC3 and jQuery.jTable / Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

Im trying to setup a table using the jQuery jTable plugin.

Atm. it's very basic. But I can't get it working. I get a JScript runtime Error every time i try and load the table.

My script looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     var listURL= $('#EnvTableContainer').attr('data-list-url');
     var deleteURL = $('#EnvTableContainer').attr('data-delete-url');
     var updateURL = $('#EnvTableContainer').attr('data-update-url');
     var createURL = $('#EnvTableContainer').attr('data-create-url');

    $('#EnvTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Environments',
            actions: {
                listAction: listURL,
                deleteAction: deleteURL,
                updateAction: updateURL,
                createAction: createURL
            },
            fields: {
                    Id: {
                        key: true,
                        create: false,
                        edit: false,
                        list: false
                    },
                    Name: {
                        title: 'Name',
                        width: '50%'

                    }
            }
    });

    $('#EnvTableContainer').jtable('load');
});
```

When I try and run it, it breaks and stops in jquery-1.8.0-min.js file on this:

```
var e,f=0,g=a.length,h=g===b
```

Anyone know what is the problem?
I have been looking at the API for jQuery.jTable. But can't find anywhere, that the length can be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are returning wrong formatted result. listAction URL must return a json object as  shown jTable's documantation: http://jtable.org/ApiReference#act-listAction

Answer (score 0):

I ended up on this page from following this wonderful guide.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277576/AJAX-based-CRUD-tables-using-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-jTa

If you happen to be following this awesome guide and end-up getting a similar error, pay attention to the caps-sensitive nature of javascript when creating your jTable instance.   I had a key field of "EmployeeId" instead of "EmployeeID" and Visual Studio gave the wonderful error.

> Unhandled exception at line 446, column 13 in  localhost:58594/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js
>
> 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'data': >object is null or undefined

Double check the structure of your jTable instance.